# TypeError: table.rows is not a function - while accessing examples from feature file in protractor

Tags: typescript, protractor, cucumberjs

I am using *protractor-cucumber-framework*

Here is the feature file

```
Feature: welcome to protractor cucumber

    Scenario Outline: DataTable
        Given I am learning
        Then I print following table

        Examples:
            | First | Middle |
            | qwerty   | xyz  |
```

in the step definition file, I wanted to print the table data.

```
    Given(/^I am learning$/, async () => {
        console.log("I am learning");   
    });

    Then(/^I print following table$/, (table: TableDefinition) => {
        const tableData = table.rows();
        console.log(tableData[0][0]);

      });
```

Bute getting following error

```
TypeError: table.rows is not a function
    at World.(anonymous) (/.../Protr_cucumber/stepDef/Sample_stepDef.ts:9:29)
```

Comment: are you sure you are looking for scenario outline?

Comment: Din't get your question, that's the only feature file content I have which I am running!

Comment: table in line object is not applicable for scenario outline, i think. This should work if scenario is just scenario, not scenario outline with examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing yourself with Scenario outline and Data tables.

Scenario outlines are used when you want to execute a scenario with multiple test data.

Data table helps in passing multiple test data to a single step in a scenario. you can access this data in step definition using `hashes` and `rows`.

You can find the docs [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/data_table_interface.md) and examples [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/features/data_tables.feature).

A more detailed documents on Gherkin is found [here](https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/).